# Change fallback font for font-display:swap

Tags: css, fonts

As far as i am aware if you use the option "**swap**" for the property "**font-display**", Apple Mac uses Helvetica as fallback font and Windows Arial. Is it possible to define my own web-safe font like "Tahoma"?

Example code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFancyFont';
  src: local('MyFancyFont'), url(/fonts/MyFancyFont/MyFancyFont.woff2) format('woff2');
  font-display: swap;
  UseMyCustomFallbackFont: Tahoma
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is done in the font-family definition, not the @font-face itself.

ex.

```css
.my-text{
  font-family: MyFancyFont, Tahoma;
}
```

This will show Tahoma until MyFancyFont is loaded.

You can get even more specific control if you use something like Webfont loader.
https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader